# Do I want Publish or Release Build in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, installation, deployment, visual-studio-2010

I wrote a little (like 40 lines little) Winforms application with VB.net in Visual Studio 2010. Now I've released the code as a Google Code project. It's easy for a developer to get the source but I'd like to make it easy to install too.

What I did was make a release build then zip up what it created, this included a setup.exe. There was also an option to "publish" my project which looks like it can enable update checks and other stuff.

In my case, I just want to make it easy for a casual user who happens to want to try out this app with as few clicks as needed. Was putting up the release build the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the "Best" method is subjective.  However, there's nothing wrong with the way you did it.  It's how I would have done it.

If you plan on providing updates, you could also look at ClickOnce (which is the "Publish" option you mentioned), but I like the way you did it better.

With ClickOnce, you'd probably need to purchase a certificate from a CA and sign your code.  If you fail to do this, then anyone who tries to use your app gets a scary security warning.  They can bypass it, but it would discourage anyone who is not familiar with it.